# Extracting multiple records from an access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I have two tables in Access like this:

```
[Groups]  
GroupID - GroupName - GroupDesc - Members
```

```
[Users]  
UserID - UserName - .... - GroupID
```

And a VBA GUI that has a Combobox (populated with Group Names) and listbox (populated with all UserNames).

I'm trying to get the Listbox to highlight all Usernames that have a GroupID matching the Group selected in the Combobox. I have gotten it to highlight the first username that matches, but can't figure out how to get it to loop through the database and find ALL usernames matching the query.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub adminGroupsGroupNameCmbox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles adminGroupsGroupNameCmbox.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim mainConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    mainConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    Using mainConnection
        mainConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT * FROM [Groups] WHERE (GroupName = '" & adminGroupsGroupNameCmbox.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, mainConnection)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        adminGroupGroupLstbx.ClearSelected()

        Using cmd
            Using dr
                While dr.Read()

                    adminGroupsGroupNameTxt.Text = dr("GroupName").ToString
                    adminGroupsGroupDescTxt.Text = dr("GroupDesc").ToString

                    'input name, get ID
                    Dim GrabbedGroupID As String = GrabGroupID(adminGroupsGroupNameTxt.Text)
                    '

                    str = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE (GroupID = '" & GrabbedGroupID & "')"
                    Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, mainConnection)
                    Dim dr2 As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader

                    Using cmd2
                        Using dr2
                            While dr2.Read()

                                Dim Username As String = dr2("UserName").ToString

                                ' Ensure we have a proper string to search for.
                                If Username <> String.Empty Then
                                    Dim idx As Integer
                                    While idx <= adminGroupGroupLstbx.Items.Count

                                        ' Find the item in the list and store the index to the item.
                                        Dim index As Integer = adminGroupGroupLstbx.FindStringExact(Username)
                                        ' Determine if a valid index is returned. Select the item if it is valid.
                                        If index <> ListBox.NoMatches Then
                                            adminGroupGroupLstbx.SetSelected(index, True)
                                        Else
                                            MessageBox.Show("The search string did not find any items in the ListBox that exactly match the specified search string")
                                        End If 'index <> ListBox.NoMatches

                                        idx = idx + 1
                                    End While 'idx <= adminGroupGroupLstbx.Items.Count

                                End If 'Username <> String.Empty

                            End While 'dr2.Read()
                        End Using 'dr2
                    End Using 'cmd2

                End While 'dr.Read()
            End Using 'dr
        End Using 'cmd
    End Using 'mainConnection
End Sub
```

Comment: Why make two queries? Can you not use an `inner join` and iterate only a single result set?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Which queries are you suggesting I join?

Comment: First you iterate `Groups`, for each `GroupID` then you iterate `Users` with that `GroupID`. I'm not sure what `GrabGroupID` does, but it seems to me you could simply be iterating `SELECT Users.* FROM Users INNER JOIN Groups ON Users.GroupID = Groups.ID WHERE GroupName = '" & adminGroupsGroupNameCmbox.Text & "'"`, or something similar to that.

Comment: Also, looking at the code, this isn't [tag:vba]... it's [tag:vb.net]... and now I'm thoroughly confused about what VB.NET is doing with Access, and what the GUI actually is.